# Charging for subscriptions/downloads with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, subscription

I have a customer who is interested in selling his set of tutorial screencasts, and he *very much* wants to do this using wordpress.

Has anyone any experience in selling subscriptions to wordpress sites, or selling digital downloads using wordpress, and is there anything I need to consider that I might have missed?

I'm currently looking at [wp-e-commerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/stats/) and also at other plugins that let you charge a subscription for access to a site, but I'm struggling to find any that don't have a cost attached. Are there any you can recommend?

Comment: Some times you have to spend money to make money. :) I wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: B...b...b...but open source hehe. Yeah I know what you mean! I have found this list, which looks very interesting. http://pennybutler.com/wordpress/plugin-reviews/wordpress-plugin-groups/20-wordpress-plugins-membership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [memberwing](http://www.memberwing.com/), they have a free version that is quite enabled and the upgrade is only ~US$100.

> • Digital Content Theft Protection and Tracing  – TraceFusion. Find out exactly who steals, illegally shares and distributes your premium materials on internet. Detect, Trace, Terminate and Prosecute members who are involved in illegal sharing of your premium digital content. TraceFusion is like CCTV security camera with night vision and recording – but implemented as a software to protect your digital property against crooks, giving you the power to protect your online business like never before.
>
> • Digital Content Download Protection. Protects your files against unauthorized downloads due to link sharing and link “guessing”. No more problems with link sharing!
>
> • Digital Content Automated Promotion (PromoFusion). When free visitor clicks or attempts to view premium download materials – he will see “promotional” version of material, instead of “access denied” or 404 error. This feature brings extra promotional powers to your membership site, keeps visitors staying longer, helps to convert visitors to buyers and gives you extra SEO boost on Google.
>
> • and more...

Comment: Didn't use this but thanks for answering.